# Sql Server 2005 Service Pack 3 does not install

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm trying to install SP3 on an install of Sql Server 2005 running on Server 2003 32 bit. When I run the installer it doesn't seem to recognize that I have SQL Server 2005 installed. The dialog box that asks what features should be updated doesn't show any by default. More troubling, it doesn't allow me to check any of those boxes to update features like Database Services or Reporting Services.

When I select one of these services, the "Status" box says "Not Valid". The message says something about more recent updates, but Select @@Version gives me this:

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4053.00 (Intel X86) 
    May 26 2009 14:24:20 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Just tossing this out there, but my knee-jerk response is to try the installation from safe mode.

Edit: Have you fully updated Windows? Have you tried stopping the SQL related services prior to upgrading? The installer should handle this kind of stuff, just trying to think of anything that may help ya..

Comment: The Windows Installer service won't run in Safe Mode without some additional coaxing.

Comment: I haven't tried safe mode. My best shot at this point is to come in on a Sunday and uninstall and then reinstall Sql Server from scratch.

Comment: Obviously you wanna make sure you have a really reliable backup of your database contents - provided there is any. Obviously obvious, indeed.